# How can I multiply two one byte hex numbers using rotation in mp8085 (dyna one)?

Tags: assembly, hex, byte, multiplication, 8085

So I've already multiplied two one byte numbers using one as counter and then repeatedly adding the other, but my teacher says its possible to multiply them by rotating one number to the right 8 times and performing addition when the carry flag is not 0, I haven't been able to perform it and have always got a wrong answer

The code is as follows

```
C000H : XRA A
MOV D, A
LHLD C030H
MOV E, L
MOV A, H
LXI 0000H
MVI C 08H
DAD H 
RRC (JUMP FROM JNZ ) 
JNC C012H
DAD D
DCR C  ( JUMP FROM JNC ) 
JNZ C00DH
SHLD C032H
HLT
```

Also this is unrelated but which free mp8085 simulator is the best? I use the one with sc labs but it seems to have some problems where it doesn't carry the higher bit properly

Comment: I'm not familiar with the hardware you're using or the assembly. It sounds like you're tasked to implement multiplication of A and B by adding powers of 2 multiples (obtained simply with left shifts) of A depending on the bit pattern of B. Is it the case the the carry flag is set when a set bit is shifted right off the end? If it is then you can use that to decide which terms to accumulate. I suggest you write it in pseudo-code first, or better still, emulate the operation using another language like c for example, then translate it to your assembly

Comment: This code gives me assembly errors (I'm using https://www.sim8085.com/).  It says that `LXI` requires two operands.  Is that my bad or what else?